# db2 select statement with group and sum

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have this data in db2 which I need a query for...

```
location | part | quantity
--------------------------
  loc1     TD3     300
  loc1     RA5       0
  loc2     MO2       8
  loc2     CY1       9
  loc2     BL5       6
  loc4     RA5      50
  loc4     PL5       5
  loc3     YT7       2
  loc3     UA9       5
```

The result set would return the `'location's` which have **less than 10** `'quantity'` for all of their `'part's`. The `'part'` doesn't need to be included in the result set. Also in the result set, I would like to sum the total of the quantities as well. So in the case above, I would get this result set.

```
location | total quantity
-------------------------
  loc2          23
  loc3          7
```

This needs to be a sql query for the database **db2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see.  This isn't quite a duplicate of your last question.  But it is a minor tweak on the query:

```
select location, sum(quantity)
from db2
group by location
having max(quantity) < 10;
```

Comment: That's correct Gordon. After putting the code into action from my previous question, I realized that it is not what I needed.